# Can I remove these span?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML/CSS code ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oyuke5/2/edit)):

```
.trackTime{width:50px; text-align:left; float:left;}
.trackInputTime{width:45px; height:22px; background-color:#F4F4F4;}   

<span class="trackTime">            
    <select name="hours[]" class="trackInputTime" id="trackInputHours" >
        <option value="??">??</option>
     </select>
</span>

<span class="trackTime">            
    <select name="minuts[]" class="trackInputTime" >
        <option value="??">??</option>
    </select>   
</span>

<span class="trackTime">                            
    <select name="seconds[]" class="trackInputTime" >
        <option value="??">??</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

And I'd like to remove the span for each select field. Tried to remove the span and edit the class ([here](http://jsbin.com/ipopu4/edit) the edited version) :

```
.trackInputTime{width:50px; height:22px; background-color:#F4F4F4; text-align:left; padding-right:5px; float:left;}
```

but there is a white background that I don't like..

The same for an input submit button :

```
.trackBotton{width:75px; float:left; text-align:right;}

<span class="trackBotton"><input type="submit" value="+ Side" onClick="addSide(this);return false" /></span>
<span class="trackBotton"><input type="submit" value="+ Track" onClick="addTrack(this);return false" /></span>
<span class="trackBotton"><input type="submit" value="Remove" onClick="remTrack(this);return false" /></span>
```

I have many of these span, that's why I'd like to remove them.

How can I do it? Can't add the jsfiddle because seems to be offline :O

Comment: put in http://jsbin.com/ if jsfiddle is offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use the spans to get some space between the form elements.
You can remove the spans and use

```
.trackInputTime{width:50px; height:22px; background-color:#F4F4F4; text-align:left; margin-right:5px; float:left;}
```

You were almost there, just use "margin" instead of "padding". Padding is extra space on the "inside" of the element, margin on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying this line to:
padding-right:0px;